# Unmarshal a generic protobuf in go

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I want to store protobuf structs into postgres using a byte array as the serialized type. I usually do this using a wrapper struct that implements the `Scan()` and `Value()` methods. I am trying to get a generic implementation for this otherwise I have to define a new struct for every new type that I want to persist.
I tried with the following approach without success:

```
type SqlProto[T proto.Message] struct {
    Valid bool
    Proto T
}

func (d SqlProto[T]) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    if value == nil {
        d.Valid = false
        return nil
    }

    bytes, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid value for %T: %v", value, value)
    }

    d.Proto = *new(T)
    err := proto.Unmarshal(bytes, d.Proto)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to parse %T: %w", value, err)
    }

    d.Valid = true

    return nil
}

func (d SqlProto[T]) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if !d.Valid {
        return nil, nil
    }

    return proto.Marshal(d.Proto)
}
```

The problem is that i get `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` since `new()` returns a nil pointer of the type that I want, but `Unmarshal` obviously fails because it expects an instantiated value.
How can I overcome this problem? I didn't find any other way to instantiate a generic type